# Save Class Instance to Vue Data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdftron

I am trying to use PDFtron in one of my Vue components. I create the pdf viewer iFrame instance in the mounted hook so that upon loading the Vue, the PDF frame shows up ready to load PDFs:

```
mounted() {
    const viewerElement = document.getElementById('viewer');
    this.viewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer({
      path: 'https://www.pdftron.com/4.0/lib',
      l: 'apikey'
    }, viewerElement);
  }
```

I would like to save this instance so that I can call it again in a method like this:

```
 methods: {
    getPDF() {
      this.viewer.loadDocument('https://pdftron.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/pl/webviewer-demo.pdf')
    }
  }
```

In order to do this I thought I could create a `viewer` variable in my data variables and then save the pdftron viewer to it which is why I save the viewer to `this.viewer`. Unfortunately whenever I call the `getPDF` function, I get the following error: `The viewer instance is not defined yet.` I am not sure if this is the correct way to save a class instance in Vue.

The `getPDF` function gets called on a button like this:

`<v-btn color="primary" @click="getPDF(url)" :disabled="!valid">Load PDF</v-btn>`'

**Update:**

I updated my getPDF function to this:

```
getPDF() {
      const viewerInstance = this.viewer.getInstance()
      viewerInstance.loadDocument('https://pdftron.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/pl/webviewer-demo.pdf')
    }
```

but I still get same error `The viewer instance is not defined yet` and `Cannot read property loadDocument of undefined'

Comment: It's probably a matter of timing. Can you show where/when the call to `getPDF` occurs?

Comment: @eric99 it's called from a button. I added it in original question.

Comment: is your `#viewerElement` in the same Vue component?

Comment: @YongQuan Yes, its in the template above like this: `<div id='viewer' style='width: 1024px; height: 600px;'> </div>`

Comment: It looks ok to me, the only thing I can suggest is declaring the viewer variable outside the component. If using a SFC, declare with `let viewer;` inside the `<script>` tag but before `export default {...`. Then reference it without `this`.

Comment: btw, `The viewer instance is not defined yet.` seems to be PDFTron's error message and not Vue's or the DOM's. If it is, then the problem is not in Vue but in PDFTron.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you are triggering the button click before WebViewer has loaded and initialized.

You cannot interact with WebViewer API (except the constructor), until you get the ready event.
https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/PDFTron.WebViewer.html#event:ready__anchor

See this page for an example.
https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/js/viewing

I would recommend adding your button listeners in the ready event listener, so users can only use those buttons once the viewer is ready.